# Как сделать кнопку неактивной после нажатия, или скрыть её (Android)

Tags: android

Как сделать кнопку неактивной после нажатия, или скрыть её?

Comment: елемент.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: Это конечно офтоп, но вот хорошие уроки по android, после поверхностного изучения отпадает большинство подобных вопросов. http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Запретить нажатие:

```
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    v.setClickable(false);
                }
            });
```

скрыть:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Как по мне наглядней будет button.setEnabled(false); Кнопка становится серой (не активной) соответственно и не кликабельной.